# HTML/Javascript - Welcome image cover that disappears after load - the web page partially reloads?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have almost completed what I'm trying to achieve - a full screen welcome image that appears on load per session and fades out on larger screens.
It also removes scrollbars during display, and re-enables on completion.

Problem is, that when it fades out, any text & background colors load or reload. Images and positioning are already loaded / fade to fine.

Any suggestions / ideas greatly appreciated.

I have tried removing css / html so it leaves me to believe it is something with the javascript.

```
if ($(window).width() > 769) {
   $(window).load(function() {
      var isshow = sessionStorage.getItem('isshow');
      if (isshow== null) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('isshow', 1);
        document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';  // firefox, chrome
        document.body.scroll = "no"; // ie only
        // Show popup here
        $.when($('#jPopup').show().delay(4000).fadeOut(2000))
        .done(function() {
            document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'auto';  // firefox, chrome
            document.body.scroll = "yes"; // ie only
         });
       }
   });
}
```

I have also tried `$(document).ready` instead of `window.load` etc.

Comment: Can you produce a [mcve], preferably as a snippet here in the question, that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass completion callback with fadeOut itself.

```
if ($(window).width() > 769) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var isshow = sessionStorage.getItem('isshow');
    if (isshow == null) {
      sessionStorage.setItem('isshow', 1);
      document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';  // firefox, chrome
      document.body.scroll = "no"; // ie only

      $("#jPopup").show().delay(4000).fadeOut(2000, function() {
          // will run upon fadeout completion
          document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'auto';  // firefox, chrome
          document.body.scroll = "yes"; // ie only
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Check working sample here: http://jsbin.com/liruxilupa

Comment: Great thanks, that helps, but I also changed the div css position properties to fixed and moved it just before </body>

Comment: Sorry didn't get that. Can you update the jsbin sample and send me link? So I can see if I can be of any help.

Comment: It's working now - I moved the div linked in the JavaScript to the bottom. And changed it's CSS property to static. Basically it loads everything before displaying the div now. Thanks for your help.